# React Javascript displaying/decoding unicode characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string in unicode that i need to convert.  I need to render the string with \u00f3 to ó. This is an example, it should happen with all other types of characters, á, í, ú...

I have the following basic code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dddf7o70/

I need to convert

```
<Hello name="Informaci\u00f3n" />
```

into

```
Información
```

Comment: Why? React and JavaScript can do Unicode just fine, why not just type what you need to type? (the docs recommends \u... notation only as a universally safer option, but by now, Unicode is pretty universally safe)

Comment: The reason why i need to convert it is because someone else is feeding me the string: Informaci\u00f3n

Comment: so this question isn't about React at all, it's "how do I convert strings with \u... notation into plain strings in JavaScript"? Because https://jsfiddle.net/dddf7o70/3/ (with real string content) works fine in React. How are you getting those strings? It seems very unlikely you'd get strings that haven't already resolved the `\u....` markers...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have to work with strings that have, for whatever reason, literally the letters `\u` followed by hexadecimals in them instead of being real letters, convert them to numbers, and then use String.fromCharCode() to turn those numbers into real letters. We can use a regexp replace with handler function for this:

```js
// put this in whatever utility library file you have:
export function convertUnicode(input) {
  return input.replace(/\\+u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, (a,b) =>
    String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b, 16)));
}
```

And then in your component:

```js
import { convertUnicode } from "...your util lib...";

function Hello(props) {
   const name = convertUnicode(props.name);
   return <div>Hello {name}</div>;
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Hello name="Informaci\\u00f3n"/>);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shdye3pq/

Answer (score 52):

Just pass it as a JS string:

```
<Hello name={'Informaci\u00f3n'} />
```

No need to do any manual processing (which is error prone).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dddf7o70/5/

Comment: Thanks zerkms, your fiddler works but for some reason react or something in my project is preventing this conversion from occuring.  Do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: @barracuda React cannot "prevent" it - whatever is between the curly braces `{ }` is interpreted as pure JS. I would suggest you to check what jsx was translated into first.

Answer (score 4):

To put the unicode write in your `render()` and ***jsx***, you can just:

```
<div>{'First \u00b7 Second'}</div>
```

, or

```
<div>{'First ' + String.fromCharCode(183) + ' Second'}</div>
```

If doing this with libraries and other fonts, be sure that your font is imported first, make sure that you are using `font-family: myFont` (i.e. `"Font Awesome 5 Free"`). And make sure that the unicode that you are using is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Question title leads to this questions around React unicode issues, and sometimes simply this `meta` tag is needed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
</html>
```