# Use a raw HTML entity in an attribute in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a line in my view like this:

```
return (<Button title='&#9654;' />)
```

which works to display the "arrow forward"  ▶ symbol.

While trying to clean it up, I tried to do something like this:

```
let arrowRight = '&#9654;';
return (<Button title={arrowRight} />)
```

But now it displays the button with a title of `&#9654;`

As an alternative, I've just put the actual unicode symbol in there and made sure the document is UTF-8 and it works fine. But it made me curious.

Is there a simple way to tell React not to html encode the string?

Comment: This might be the solution you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166758/react-javascript-displaying-decoding-unicode-characters

Comment: This is not an *attribute* but a *prop*. A simple way is to not use HTML entity in the first place, `let arrowRight = '▶';`